# Poor performance on React-Native application (iOS and Android)

Tags: react-native, performance

So I have a question about my application.
Details about the app:

- It's made in React-Native
- it's like a social-media
- You can post videos
- You have profile/notifications etc

So, my problem is with the loading screen. Every time I switch between tabs on the menu bar, first I get the loading screen, then the actual page. Even if I switch back and forth fast, I have the same result.

My question is:
Do I need CDN? I know I need CDN for videos(I don't have at the moment), but the pages without CDN should run smooth, rigt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For react-native app's views:

- Ensure to include all general images in the assets, and don't use CDN there.
- The images should not be too heigh resolution, as resize takes process time.
- Lastly, you must be showing a custom-loading manually, as experience shows (for me tabs open instantly).

  - The loading should only cover what is being loaded, not entire view.

Comment: Thank you! I tested right now more things on my phone(iOS). If I go now on notifications page(With user's profile pictures), the page is loading without the loading screen. It seems that only the profile page is loading(with loading screen). Here I only have my profile picture, 1 video(thumbnail), 4 icons for socials, views/likes/my name/description(only text). Still, I'm wondering why notification page works fine(there are multiple profile pictures/names/text)

Comment: @Alexander Maybe because said faster-view does not show videos; Now to fix, the custom-loading should be changed, so that it's only visible in the video frame (not over the entire profile view).